# Inclusion of data via database in an impex

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

This is my impex:

```
    INSERT_UPDATE ReferenceProductAttributeValue;leaf(code,name[lang=de])[unique=true];newvalue(pk)
```

I have to put in **newvalue(pk)** the **pk** of `units.p_code="PCE"` that first, I have to take it from my databas e.Here is my query that it works perfectly in my MySQL:

```
      SELECT `units`.`PK` FROM `my_schema`.`units` WHERE `units`.`p_code`="PCE";
```

I allready tried this:

```
    INSERT_UPDATE ReferenceProductAttributeValue;leaf(code,name[lang=de])[unique=true];newvalue(pk)
          ;001:Antiviren-Software (Client-Betriebssystem);
   "#% 
      impex.initDatabase( <myDburl>, <myUser>, <myPassword>, <MyDriver.class>);"
   "#% 
      impex.includeSQLData( 
      "" SELECT ""+
      "" units.PK ""+"" FROM my_schema.units ""+
      "" WHERE ""+
      "" units.p_code ='PCE'""
      );"
```

and this:

```
    INSERT_UPDATE ReferenceProductAttributeValue;leaf(code,name[lang=de])[unique=true];newvalue(pk)
                  ;001:Antiviren-Software (Client-Betriebssystem);
    "#%
     import  de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.FlexibleSearchQuery;
     flexibleSearchService = Registry.getApplicationContext().getBean(""flexibleSearchService"");
     query = "" SELECT {units.PK} FROM {my_schema.units} WHERE {units.p_code} LIKE '%PCE%' "";
     flexibleSearchQuery = new FlexibleSearchQuery(query);
     resultIterator = flexibleSearchService.search(flexibleSearchQuery).getResult().iterator();"
```

but it didn't work. Can someone give me a hint?

A new try:

```
     INSERT_UPDATE ReferenceProductAttributeValue;newvalue(pk);leaf(code,name[lang=de])[unique=true]
     #% beforeEach:
     #% import de.hybris.platform.core.model.product.UnitModel;
     #% import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.FlexibleSearchQuery;
     #% import de.hybris.platform.jalo.flexiblesearch.* ;
     #% import de.hybris.platform.core.Registry;
     #% flexibleSearchService = Registry.getApplicationContext().getBean("flexibleSearchService");
     #% query = "SELECT {" + UnitModel.PK + "} FROM {" + UnitModel._TYPECODE + "} WHERE {" + UnitModel.CODE + "} = 'PCE' ";
     #% flexibleSearchQuery = new FlexibleSearchQuery(query);
     #% resultIterator = flexibleSearchService.search(flexibleSearchQuery).getResult().iterator().next();
     #% beforeEach: end \
     ;001:Antiviren-Software (Client-Betriebssystem)
```

now I don´t have Errors any more but stil don´t have my searched pk in newvalue. Can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

so my solution is that I made a translator that looks like this (this is just for other beginner like me, maybe are another Solutions also but for me this was enough, it does work. If someone with more experience like to improve the Code, please ... ):

```
   public class UnitByCodeTranslator extends AbstractSpecialValueTranslator
{
 ...

/*
 *
 * @see de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.translators.AbstractSpecialValueTranslator#performImport(java.lang.String,
 * de.hybris.platform.jalo.Item)
 */
@Override
public void performImport(final String cellValue, final Item item) throws ImpExException
{
            if ((item instanceof ReferenceProductAttributeValue))
    {
    final ReferenceProductAttributeValueModel referenceProdAttVal = (ReferenceProductAttributeValueModel) modelService.get(item.getPK());
    final String value = cellValue;
    final UnitModel unit = new UnitModel();
    try
    {
        unit.setCode(value);
        final UnitModel foundUnit = flexibleSearchService.getModelByExample(unit);
        referenceProdAttVal.setNewValue(foundUnit);
        modelService.save(referenceProdAttVal);
    }
    catch (final UnknownIdentifierException e)
    {
        LOGGER.warn("Could not find a Unit for this " + value);
    }
    catch (final AmbiguousIdentifierException e)
    {
        LOGGER.warn(e.toString());
        throw new UnresolvedValueException(e.toString());
    }
    }
}

....
}
```

The impex then is like this:

```
INSERT_UPDATE ReferenceProductAttributeValue;leaf(code,name[lang=de])[unique=true];@newvalue[translator=com.myextension.core.impex.translators.UnitByCodeTranslator]
;001:AGP-Grafikkarte;PCE
```

Comment: This is far too complicated. This is much simpler: 

    INSERT_UPDATE ReferenceProductAttributeValue;leaf(code,name[lang=de])[unique=true];newvalue(code);
    ;001:AGP-Grafikkarte;PCE;

Comment: <itemtype code="ReferenceProductAttributeValue" extends="ProductAttributeValue" jaloclass="myextention.core.jalo.ReferenceProductAttributeValue">
    <deployment table="CCReferenceProdAttribVal" typecode="29100"/>
    <attributes>
     <attribute type="Item" qualifier="newValue" >
       <persistence type="property"/>
       <modifiers optional="true" />
     </attribute>
    </attributes>
   </itemtype>

Comment: It is not so easy, I already tried that. newvalue is an Item and I am not allowed to change that, thats why I tried to implement at the first time that in impex  , but I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: In that case try:  INSERT_UPDATE ReferenceProductAttributeValue;leaf(code,name[lang=de])[unique=true];newvalue(Unit.code); ;001:AGP-Grafikkarte;PCE;

Comment: nop... it doesn't work . I tried it allrready.  newvalue accepts just pk.

Comment: What is the error message? Did you recognize the Unit.code in my last comment? "newvalue(Unit.code)"

Answer (score 1):

Try with code

```
newvalue(code)[default='PCE']
```

Comment: :(, it doesn't work because newvalueunit is not an Attribute of ReferenceProductAttributeValue , and i receive an error:  "Importskript ist ungültig: unknown attribute 'newvalueunit' in header 'INSERT_UPDATE ReferenceProductAttributeValue' ". Code with value='PCE' is an attribute of Unit that I have to put like a pk in newvalue that is of type Item and an attribute of ReferenceProductAttributeValue.

Comment: Better you add data model details(*items.xm) in your question.

Comment: Use this impex. HybrisHelp just used the wrong attribute name: 

    INSERT_UPDATE ReferenceProductAttributeValue;leaf(code,name[lang=de])[unique=true];newvalue(code);
    ;001:AGP-Grafikkarte;PCE;

Comment: @JohannesNolte - Thanks, let me correct the attribute name (newvalue)!!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is dependent on the type of newValue.

If its type is Unit, you can reference it by one or more attributes of type Unit, that identify this item uniquely (e.g. code):

```
newvalue(code)
```

If its type is more generic, like Item, you need to use a unique attribute of that type. The only unique attribute for Item is PK. But you don't want to reference you Unit by PK. Therefore you can define which type should be used by prefixing the attribute with the typecode of the type you want to reference:

```
newValue(Unit.code)
```

In a complete statement this would look like this:

```
INSERT_UPDATE ReferenceProductAttributeValue;leaf(code,name[lang=de][unique=true];newvalue(Unit.code); 
;001:AGP-Grafikkarte;PCE;
```

---

You can also reference other items you used in an impex statement before with the & operator. The & operator defines references. You define them in you header like this:

```
INSERT_UPDATE Unit;code[unique=true];$unitRef;
;pieces;PIECES_REF;
;cm;CM_REF;
```

Then you can use the reference later to reference a value:

```
INSERT_UPDATE ReferenceProductAttributeValue;leaf(code,name[lang=de][unique=true];newvalue(&unitRef); 
;001:AGP-Grafikkarte;PIECES_REF;
```